# How to find out how long my task is taking

Tags: shell, command-line

Not the cpu time but the real world time.

This is what I do right now.

```
date
my_task
date
```

But this requires keeping an eye on the screen all 5 mts. There should be a better way.

I'm using mac.

Comment: 5 mts was just an example. some of the tasks take 2 mts and some 4 .

Comment: I can bash them but was wondering if there is some native command that I am missing

Comment: time is the answer. thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4):

Use the time command:

```
time my_task
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had luck switching to zsh and using this:

http://blog.tobez.org/2009/03/how-to-time-command-execution-in-zsh.html

(Note the reference to REPORTTIME in the comments.)